# Frequency of cascaded counter

Tags: digital-logic, counter, homework

**Question:**

> Consider one set of \$Mod-14\$ digital-counter having input clock frequncy \$19kHz\$.If another input clock frequency as first one is cascaded then final output clock frequency of the composite counter will be?
>
> \$(A)1kHz (B)4.75kHz (C)0.28kHz (D)2.1kHz\$

---

As the \$mod-n\$ counter will divides output frequency by n.So output of first counter will be \$19kHz/14\$,which is fed to another counter of mod 14 ,then  it will again divide output by 14,So

\$\frac{19\times10^3Hz}{14\times14}=96.93 Hz\$

But here no option is matching.

Comment: It looks right the way you've assumed the question, but the question is very badly formulated. However if you just divide 19kHz by  the different answers you get A(19), B(4), C(67.85), D(9) (if D = 2.1111111) - So the only two answers that gave "perfect" integers are B and D if D had some more digits. If I were you I'd try to do some reverse engineering with B or D.

Comment: Complete jibberish as written.  "one" (singular) sets (plural) with "another input clock" with unspecified frequency?  Ignore question and move on.